# How to send Command prompt output to android

Tags: android, cmd, output

I am creating an app in which it will send some command to server and i want to get the output of that command on client (android).

Basically i am sending command "systeminfo" and the output is too big to handle, so is there any way to get that big output on android as text view or anything else?

Code is as below

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("systeminfo");
```

and for get the output i have used

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

I am confused how to use it as too much of string. Any reference material would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to reconstruct each line from the `BufferedReader`

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line).append("\n"); // Remove the \n if you don't want newlines
}

final String execOutput = builder.toString();
```

Comment: will try and let u inform